# How to have a Tabbar of a Cordova app nicely fit with various mobile screen sizes?

Tags: css, html, cordova, responsive, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a tabbar component in my Cordova app developed on Meteor and React. I want to be sure that the tabbar (or footer) will always be placed at the bottom of a mobile screen while the body is scrollable. The mockup in the picture is illustrating a mobile screen with a scrollable content and a tabbar. 
Secondly, I want to ensure that the tabbar will nicely fit to various sizes of different mobile devices.
I am not sure if these two are related completely with CSS or viewport settings or Cordova config.xml.
What is the best way to address these two needs?

[image: A basic mockup illustrating a tabbar]

Answer (score 0):

I would create an html div with an id "tabBar" and some CSS like this:

```
#tabBar {
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
background:#000;
color:#fff;
width:100%;
height:50px;}
```

Then you could have icon divs associated with classes, like:

```
#tabBar .icon {
float:left;
width:25%;
height:100%;
color:#ffffff;}
```